# Cannot figure out how to proceed: Java Bug~

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  private static int decimalNum = 0;
  private static String binary = "";

  private static void getInput() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type in a number");
    decimalNum = sc.nextInt();
  }

  private static void convert() {
    int decimalNumber = decimalNum;
    String binaryNumber;
    if (decimalNumber <= 0)
      System.out.println("ERROR: entered integer is nonpositive.");
    else {
      binaryNumber = "";
      while (decimalNumber != 0) {
        // add spaces to separate 4-digit groups
        if (binaryNumber.length() % 5 == 0)
          binaryNumber = "" + binaryNumber;
        // extract last digit in binary representation
        // and add it to binaryNumber
        binaryNumber = (decimalNumber % 2) + binaryNumber;
        // cut last digit in binary representation
        decimalNumber /= 2;
      }
      binary = binaryNumber;
      System.out.println("Binary: " + binaryNumber);
    }
  }

  public static void count() {
    String s = binary + "";
    System.out.println("Binary number: " + s);
    int temp1Block = 0;
    int temp0Block = 0;
    int maxBlock = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if ((s.charAt(i) == '1') && (i < s.length())) {
        temp0Block = 0;
        temp1Block++;
      }
      if ((s.charAt(i) == '0') && (i < s.length())) {
        temp1Block = 0;
        temp0Block++;
      }
    }
    if (maxBlock < temp0Block) {
      maxBlock = temp0Block;
    }
    if (maxBlock < temp1Block) {
      maxBlock = temp1Block;
    }
    System.out.println("Maxblock " + maxBlock);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getInput();
    convert();
    count();
  }
}
```

I am resetting the tempBlocks when I should not be. And can someone help me format my code please, I don't know how to put the code tags.

Comment: Simply hit the format button in the SO editor.  What problem are you having?

Comment: You might want to format this in your IDE first - it's pretty difficult to follow when all the statements for a single method are on a single line!

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions to multiple SE sites. Stack Overflow is the correct place for your question, although as I said on Programmers, it needs more detail. If you're resetting tempBlocks when you shouldn't be, just stop doing that? What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you told us what you DO want!

Comment: I need to reset. The problem is I am having hard time keeping track of the maximum block.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself?  I can't see what you mean by a "maximum block".  EDIT... nevermind... i see it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your loop would be better off like this: (I've remove some reduncant checks on 'i' and simplified the checking for 'maxBlock'):

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == '1') {
        // in case we were just keeping track of 0's
        maxBlock = Math.max(maxBlock, temp0Count);
        temp0Count = 0;

        temp1Count++;
    }
    else {
        // in case we were just keeping track of 1's
        maxBlock = Math.max(maxBlock, temp1Count);
        temp1Count = 0;

        temp0Count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to paste the answer, just in case someone in the feature:

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to keep track of the longest sequence of 1s or 0s. If that is the case, then try putting the two if statements that check the maxBlock condition inside the loop.